# angular.min.js:36 Uncaught Error

Tags: angularjs

I'm just getting started with AngularJS and boy are these error messages cryptic:

```
angular.min.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=a3d&p1=Error…s.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0-beta.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A381)
```

How do I even begin to determine what line of my code this might be referring to?

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had just created a new module and custom directive but forgot to include its source in my index.html file.  So I went ahead and added the following to my `<body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="indexChart.js"></script>
```

This fixed the problem.